# Why is not None returns True but None does not equate to True

Tags: python

```py
not None is False -> True
```

so I'd expect

```py
None is True -> True
```

but this is not the case, is there some inner working of the `None` class to be like this?

I actually only ever used `if xxx is not None` to check for boolean and never thought that if I used `if xxx is None`, which will evaluate to `False` and my logic will be wrong.

Is this behaviour expected?

Comment: This is the same as asking why does `if x` evaluate to true and `if not x` evaluate to false for the same value of `x`. That's just how boolean logic works.

Comment: `None is False` is false, so applying `not` to that makes it true.  Were you expecting `not None` to be evaluated first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you are doing

```
>>> not None is False
True
>>> None is True
False
```

And you are wondering why the second one outputs `False`.

This is because `not None is False` is the same as `not (None is False)` which is `not False` which is `True`. On the other hand `None is True` just evaluates immediately to `False`.

On a side note, you seem to think that `not None is False` would evaluate as `(not None) is False`. However, if this were the case, the result would be `False` by this evaulation:

```
(not None) is False -> True is False -> False
```

So this can't be the correct interpretation because this is not the result we get.

The key here is to evaluate one piece of an expression at a time. If you are familiar with order of operations (PEMDAS) from math, python has similar rules for all operators. Understanding this order of operations is critical for evaluating any expression in python.

Answer (score -1):

`None` or `empty iterable` or `False` all will not be executed by `if` statement.

so

```
>>> not None is False
True
>>> None is True
False
>>> arr = list()
>>> if arr:
...     print ("*.*")
... 
>>> arr.append(1)
>>> if arr:
...     print ("*.*")
... 
*.*
>>>
```